# Is it possible to include some maven url to an AAR?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar, maven-publish

Example

Suppose that some library module depends on Foo maven url (ex jitpack etc not mavencentral or google).
Then it publish It’s library module, when the user use the library, I want to avoid having to add to users use it Foo maven url to build.gradle.

Code sample

https://github.com/kwmt/databinding-ktx

I asked about it on bellow repository, but it couldn't solve.
https://github.com/wada811/DataBinding-ktx/issues/11

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Can you please provide a code snippet to explain a little more?

Comment: To be honest it hasn't been getting clearer what you really like to do and why? Please explain more in detail what you like to do?